405 with @RestController despire @DeleteMapping
When I was developping my api with spring boot and test it with Postman,I faced this issue .this is my test case i postman: curl --location --request DELETE 'http://localhost:8087/api/employee/18'.
and i got this response
{
    "timestamp": "2024-12-16T15:02:27.196+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/api/employee/18"
}

please i need help for resolve this problem! that's my code for deleting an employee from database,I have trying many times but in vain :that's my code and pom.xml file:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tech</groupId>
    <artifactId>cours-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cours-jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        super();
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Long employeeId){
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                                                      @RequestBody Employee employee){
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.updateEmployee(employee, id),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="{id}",method= {RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.GET})
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Employee deleted Successfully!",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    |
}

when I send the request for deleting the employee i got this error message in the console:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' is not supported]


You might want to try replacing @RequestMapping("/api/employee") by @RequestMapping("/api/employee/")
